# python - crontab to run a script

Tags: python, cron

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to create a cronjob through a python script but I keep getting an error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated it to show me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

**python script**

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)

job = cron.new(command='python /Users/<useraccount>/Desktop/my_script.py')
job.minute.on(2)
job.hour.on(12)

cron.write()
```

**Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<useraccount>/Desktop/01-python-crontab.py", line 3, in <module>
    cron = CronTab(user=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Comment: It looks like giving the `user=True` argument isn't valid. Have you looked at the documentation for the `crontab` module?

Answer (score 7):

Here was the issues:

Error showed up:  TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 argument

documentaton: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab helped to resolve the issue.

Reason: 
1 - crontab was installed not python-crontab

Here's the completed code:

```
def main(): 
    from crontab import CronTab

    cron = CronTab(user=True)

    job = cron.new(command='python /opt/my_script.py')
    job.minute.on(2)
    job.hour.on(12)

    cron.write()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: This was my exact problem. Un-installing crontab then installing python-crontab fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may be using an old version of crontab (See - Documentation for [1.4.1 here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/1.4.1)) . You can either upgrade to latest version of python-crontab using -

```
pip install python-crontab --upgrade
```

Or download the 1.9.3 version from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) and install it.

If you want to use the old version, you can pass in the `username` as the argument, Example -

```
cron = CronTab('<username>')
```

Comment: I was using crontab-0.21.3 instead of python-crontab. Had to 'pip uninstall crontab' and then install the new version. Thanks.